# Comparing user-inputted characters in C

Tags: c, char

The following code snippets are from a C program.

The user enters Y or N.

```
char *answer = '\0';

scanf (" %c", answer);

if (*answer == ('Y' || 'y'))
    // do work
```

I can't figure out why this `if` statement doesn't evaluate to true.

I checked for the y or n input with a `printf` and it is there, so I know I'm getting the user input. Also when I replace the the condition of the if statement with 1 (making it true), it evaluates properly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see two problems:

The pointer `answer` is a `null` pointer and you are trying to dereference it in `scanf`, this leads to *undefined behavior*.

You don't need a `char` pointer here. You can just use a `char` variable as:

```
char answer;
scanf(" %c",&answer);
```

Next to see if the read character is `'y'` or `'Y'` you should do:

```
if( answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y') {
  // user entered y or Y.
}
```

If you *really* need to use a char pointer you can do something like:

```
char var;
char *answer = &var; // make answer point to char variable var.
scanf (" %c", answer);
if( *answer == 'y' || *answer == 'Y') {
```

Comment: why is it necessary to put a space before %c in scanf? for me its not working if i remove the space before %c in scanf.

Comment: @hunch From the man page (scanf (3): 

[... for type modifier character "c"...] The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. To skip white space first, use an explicit space in the format. [...]

I assume that your Input Stream has some spaces left that pop out when you access the stream, thus "skipping" your scanf. Guess you found that out already...

Answer (score 9):

`answer` shouldn't be a pointer, the intent is obviously to hold a character.  `scanf` takes the address of this character, so it should be called as

```
char answer;
scanf(" %c", &answer);
```

Next, your "or" statement is formed incorrectly.

```
if (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y')
```

What you wrote originally asks to compare `answer` with the result of `'Y' || 'y'`, which I'm guessing isn't quite what you wanted to do.

Comment: I changed it but for some reason the body of the if statement still isnt evaluating

Comment: @Joe, had a slight typo with an extra paren, if you copied and pasted from my answer it'd likely have failed.

Answer (score 5):

Because comparison doesn't work that way. `'Y' || 'y'` is a logical-or operator; it returns `1` (true) if either of its arguments is true. Since `'Y'` and `'y'` are both true, you're comparing `*answer` with 1.

What you want is `if(*answer == 'Y' || *answer == 'y')` or perhaps:

```
switch (*answer) {
  case 'Y':
  case 'y':
    /* Code for Y */
    break;
  default:
    /* Code for anything else */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For a start, your `answer` variable should be of type `char`, not `char*`.

As for the `if` statement:

```
if (answer == ('Y' || 'y'))
```

This is first evaluating `'Y' || 'y'` which, in Boolean logic (and for ASCII) is true since both of them are "true" (non-zero). In other words, you'd only get the `if` statement to fire if you'd somehow entered <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (again, for ASCII, and where a true values equates to 1)<sup>*a</sup>.

You *could* use the more correct:

```
if ((answer == 'Y') || (answer == 'y'))
```

but you really should be using:

```
if (toupper(answer) == 'Y')
```

since that's the more portable way to achieve the same end.

---

<sup>*a</sup> You may be wondering why I'm putting in all sorts of conditionals for my statements. While the vast majority of C implementations use ASCII and certain known values, it's not necessarily mandated by the ISO standards. I know for a fact that at least one compiler still uses EBCDIC so I don't like making unwarranted assumptions.