# C++: Boolean Expression Causing Infinite While Loop

Tags: c++

In my introductory computer science class, a prompt asked us:

"Given  a char variable  c that has already  been declared , write some code that repeatedly reads a value  from standard input into c until  at last a 'Y' or 'y' or 'N' or 'n' has been entered."

The code I entered causes an infinite loop, but the logic makes sense to me. Can somebody please explain why the following Boolean expression is faulty?

```
while (c != ('n' || 'N' || 'y' || 'Y'))

  cin >> c;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing user-inputted characters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911653/comparing-user-inputted-characters-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in your loop is incorrect.

The correct condition is:

```
while ( c != 'n' && c != 'N' && c != 'y' && c != 'Y' )
{
    // ...
}
```

When you write:

```
while (c != ('n' || 'N' || 'y' || 'Y'))
```

You ask if `c` is different from `('n' || 'N' || 'y' || 'Y')`. But this expression itself will be evaluated as `true` because non-zero values ORd together are always evaluated as `true`. So your condition is equivalent to:

```
while( c != true )
```

Wich will lead to an infinite loop...

Answer (score 7):

Because that expression does not do what you think it does. The correct is

```
while (c !='n' && c != 'N' && c!= 'y' && c != 'Y')
```

But what happens with the one you present above?

```
('n' || 'N' || 'y' || 'Y')
```

This is a series of 4 boolean ORs. The first one is `'n' || 'N'`, where the `char`s `'n'` and `'N'` are converted to booleans (both `true`), therefore the whole expression is `true`.

So you are left with

```
while (c != true)
```

which is the same as `c != 1`, and goes into a loop until you input the character with ASCII value 1. Since that is not a printable character, no input from the keyboard is going to get you out of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

This:

`while (c != ('n' || 'N' || 'y' || 'Y'))`

is equivalent to:

`while (c != true )`

because any group of values ORd together is going to evaluate to `true` when one or more of them is non-zero. What you're probably looking for is:

`while ( c != 'n' && c != 'N' && c != 'y' && c != 'Y' )`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while (c !='n' && c!='N' && c!= 'y' && c!='Y')

cin >> c;
```

You are "OR"ing `'n','N','y','Y'` which always equals to true ( non zero). This is reason The loop is not terminating.

Comment: Your suggestion will also always evaluate to `true`, since it can't be all four values simultaneously. You need to use `&&`, not `||`.